# «Что» — какая часть речи?

Tags: значение-слов, части-речи

*Иван Петрович объявил отцу, **что** он напрасно укоряет его в безнравственности.*
Какой частью речи является «что» в данном предложении?

Comment: Ирина, а свои предположения есть?

Comment: либо союз, либо местоимение, это логично. но я не понимаю, сколько правил уже пересмотрела

Comment: То есть у Вас имеется непонимание того, СКОЛЬКО правил Вы уже пересмотрели?

Answer (score 2):

> И тут же спокойным, ровным голосом, хотя с внутренней дрожью во всех членах, Иван Петрович объявил отцу, **что** он напрасно укоряет его в безнравственности...
> И. С. Тургенев. Дворянское гнездо

Во-первых, "что" можно убрать из предложения и заменить двоеточием — смысл при этом практически не изменится.
*...Иван Петрович объявил отцу: он напрасно укоряет его в безнравственности...*

Во-вторых, логическое ударение (усиление интонации на слове) поставить нельзя, также к "что" невозможно поставить вопрос от членов придаточного предложения (то есть членом предложения не является).

"Что" в этом предложении — союз.

[Союзы и союзные слова](https://grammatika-rus.ru/soyuzy-i-soyuznye-slova/)

Answer (score 1):

Возьмём два предложения:
Она знала, что произойдёт. (‟Что” – местоимение, так как является членом придаточного предложения – подлежащим.)
Она знала, что произойдёт чудо. (‟Что” – союз, так как не является членом предложения, а только выполняет функцию связи.)

Хотя я, исключительно для себя, считаю, что в предложении: ‟Она знала, что произойдёт” – ‟что” является и союзом, и местоимением одновременно, так как выполняет и функцию связи, и является членом предложения (сравните: ‟Она знала, что произойдёт” и ‟Она знала: горе произойдёт”). Выстраивать терминологию таким образом, на мой взгляд, является более правильным. Но это неофициально, а официально так, как было описано выше.

В вашем предложении ‟что” – союз.

Comment: "ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО ДЛЯ СЕБЯ" у Вас в запятых. Как это объяснить? И в каких случаях запятые не нужны? В Нацкорпусе примеров без запятых много.

Comment: Если это член предложения, как в предложении: ‟Я сделал это для себя”, то запятые, конечно, не нужны, но в моём случае ‟исключительно для себя” является вставкой.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!!